# Charge distribution in series combination of capacitors

Tags: homework-and-exercises, charge, capacitance, batteries

[image]

its a normal series combination of capacitors,only the inner plates are placed differently,one in the beginning and one in the middle,will it not alter the charge distribution ? that is if we will start the charge distribution on the plates from left to right,thanks.

Comment: It's not really "series combination of capacitors" as plates 1 and 3 (counting from the left) are connected to each other but not to the other two. You know that Q1 = -Q3 and Q2 = -Q4 ... but in the case of 2 and 3, their charge will be divided between their two surfaces. Question for you: does the distribution have to be the same on both sides of the plate? If so, why? If not, why not?

Comment: the book's answer says its a series combination of three capacitors.

Comment: Can you draw an equivalent circuit that shows three capacitors? I think I see two in parallel in series with a third.

Comment: m unable to draw the circuit as charge distributions will be different,what i can do is i can displace the first plate and place it after the third plate from the left in the picture so that it l behave as a series combination of three capacitors.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should forget about categorizing this arrangements of plates as being in parallel or in series and look at the problem in a different way.

Calling the plate on the left $1$, the potentials of plates $1$ and $3$ are the same and they are electrically isolated.
This tells you something important about the magnitude of the electric field between the plates $1$ and $2$, and between $2$ and $3$.
From this you can get the relative distribution of charges on the plates and hence solve the problem.

---

Another way is to find the distribution of charges which minimises the electric potential energy of the system of charges on the plates.

Comment: that means we need to start from plate 2 having right side positive,plate 3 left side negative,plate 1 right side positive and plate 4 left side negative,if that is the case then plate 1 and plate 2 will not have electric field in the picture,cant we start charge distribution from plate 1,thanks.

Comment: Start with a charge of $-Q$ on the left side of plate 4 and a total charge of $+Q$ on plate 2.

Comment: can u pl look into my next post https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/333862/non-zero-electric-field-outside-a-capacitor